# What's a "retail pol"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In various news articles, I've come across the phrase ***retail pol***. What does it mean?

Here are some examples from online:

> [Matt Viser](https://twitter.com/mviser/status/574024740853170176), Boston Globe, via tweet:
>
> What kind of **retail pol** will Jeb be? @ananavarro insists he won't guess the ages of young children, like Romney.

---

> David Paul Kuhn, *The Atlantic*, [Forget the Retail Politicking: Presidents Are Made Wholesale](http://www.theatlantic.com/politics/archive/2011/12/forget-the-retail-politicking-presidents-are-made-wholesale/249581/)
>
> Barack Obama won the presidency. And Obama is no **retail pol**. This is why President Obama struggles to convey the spirit of these hard times.
>
> ...
>
> In 2008, Mike Huckabee was Republicans' best **retail pol**. Huckabee, however, still languished in single digits until his second place finish at the ultimate foe retail event, the Iowa straw poll.

---

> *Double Down: Game Change 2012* By John Heilemann, Mark Halperin
>
> As a **retail pol**, Santorum still left much to be desired. He was windy, dour, and digressive -- senatorial in all respects. But his crushing defeat in 2006 seemed to have imbued him with a degree of humility, and he exhibited none of the slickness, phoniness, or cartoonishness of some of his rivals.

---

> Evan Osnos, *New Yorker*, [Born Red](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/04/06/born-red)
>
> Western politicians often note that Xi has the habits of a **retail pol**: comfort on the rope line, gentle questions for every visitor, homey anecdotes.

From the *Atlantic* title, it appears *retail* is meant to be in the opposite sense of *wholesale*, and from the examples, *pol* probably means *politician*, but I'm still not 100% sure of its meaning.

What is the phrase's definition? That is, what is a *retail pol* and what are their characteristics?

What is the origin of this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **/politician/politico/pol/** that practices, well . . ., **retail politics.** :-)

Several definitions for your comparative pleasure:

> [**retail politics**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/retail+politics)  noun 1. (functioning as pl) (informal) the practice of a **politician soliciting in person for votes from the public**

_

> [Dictionary of Politics: Selected American and Foreign ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=1dtn0olA8PcC&pg=PA440&dq=%22retail%20politics%22%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G5EoVbWrIM_-sATL34GADw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22retail%20politics%22%20dictionary&f=false) - Page 440 Walter John Raymond - 1992
>
> **Retail Politics.** A mode of **campaigning for public elective office by reaching important individuals in person on the local level rather than through the media.** Although exposure through the media—radio, television, and the press—is important in any effort to reach the voters. all politics is considered local, therefore there is no substitute for a personal encounter. Grass-roots issues are more important than national or international problems according to this theory.

_

> [A Glossary of U.S. Politics and Government](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YyN6sq5vRQ8C&pg=PA150&dq=%22retail%20politics%22%20glossary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aYooVaSVBabasAT-l4D4Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22retail%20politics%22%20glossary&f=true) - Page 150 Alex Thomson - 2007
>
> **retail politics** Political strategies and campaigns that are aimed at selling a candidate and policies to a broad, mass audience. Issues are generalised, and actions designed to generate mass appeal. The opposite of ‘retail politics’ is ‘wholesale politics’, where strategies are more focused, and tailored to appeal to a select group of more demanding customers/voters/interests.

Comment: That last definition seems to be backwards - I'm not sure they've got that the right way around.

Comment: I found it myself quite confusing, so I went out and found the 2nd:-)

Answer (score 0):

*Retail pol* is an abbreviated form of the longer phrase *retail politician*, meaning a politician who practices retail politics.

The central notion implied by the term *retail politics* is that of selling one's ideas to individual consumers (voters), preferably in small-group or one-on-one settings—as opposed to *wholesale politics*, where one tries to sell one's ideas to a mass audience, as through TV ads or televised "stump" speeches or interviews at major media outlets.

In its classic form, retail politics involves having a candidate go door-to-door in his or her district, meeting and interacting with individual voters in hopes of making a positive personal impression on each of them with regard to the candidate's likability and sensible views.

Grant Barrett, *The Oxford Dictionary of American Political Slang* (2004) includes an entry for the closely related term *retail campaign*:

> **retail campaign** *n.* precisely targeted electioneering. Cf. WHOLESALE [CAMPAIGN] [Cited examples:] **1965** *New York Times* (June 5) 18: His organization for the mayoral campaign will resemble a supermarket chain, even to the opening of 76 store-front branches in the city's 76 Assembly District. "This is going to be a decentralized, retail campaign." **2000** *Marketing News* (Feb. 28) XXXIV 10: The presidential campaign is shifting from town halls to television sets as candidates trade the retail campaigning of Iowa and New Hampshire for a multistate advertising blitz. **2002** V. O'Regan & S. Stambaugh, in *White House Studies* (Sum.): This retail politics is nearly impossible in highly-populated states dominated by mass media markets and wholesale campaigning. Sparsely-populated states are more conducive to retail campaigns where the voters expect to meet and know the candidates personally.)